# Regular Time Interval - App Pool Settings

Tags: iis-7

Someone on our prod server had set the "Regular Time Interval" setting in the Recycling section to 0 on our app pool advanced properties.  Well, I tried that on our dev server.  And I get this error:

The 'Idle Time-out (minutes)' property of the application pool's process model must be less than the 'Regular Time Interval (minutes)' property of the application pool's period restart.

The Idle Time-out value in the Process Model section has a value of 20, just like our prod server.  So what gives?  How were we able to do the same thing in production but not on this attempt here?  Is there a special value you need to specify to force a zero?

Answer (score 5):

> To work around this problem, disable the Regular Time Interval (in
>   minutes) property. To do this, use one of the following methods.
>
> **Method 1**
>
> ```
> 1. Open IIS Manager.
> 2. In the Connections pane, expand the server node, and then click Application Pools.
> 3. Select the application pool for which you want to change the settings, and then click Recycling in the Actions pane.
> 4. Click to clear the Regular time intervals (in minutes) check box.
> 5. Click Next, and then follow the instructions to complete the wizard.
> ```
>
> **Method 2**
>
> ```
> 1. In the Start Search box, type command prompt, right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as administrator.
> 2. In the Administrator: Command Prompt window, type a command that resembles the following, and then press ENTER:
>      cd \windows\system32\inetsrv
> 3. Type the following command, and then press ENTER:
>      appcmd set apppool /apppool.name:[DefaultAppPool]/recycling.periodicRestart.time:00:00:00
> Note The placeholder [DefaultAppPool] represents the name of the application pool that you want to edit.
> ```

From [Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/954871).

Comment: This got me the answer I was looking for which was how to set the interval minutes to 0.  Odd that you have to specify it as a timespan. I could not find anywhere else that clearly documents this parameter value for `appcmd` usage.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the "Advanced Settings" window where I got this error, I used the "Recycling" settings menu.

Answer (score 1):

You set the Regular Time Interval and Idle Time-out (minutes) so that you can enter your value for Regular Time Interval, after that you go to Recycling setting and deactivate  Regular time intervals(in minutes)

now you have 0 in the Regular Time intervals but your value in the Idle Time-out is not changed

Answer (score 0):

I found this article:
http://forums.iis.net/t/1160032.aspx

> This is a bug in the IIS UI - you will have to set it using some other method (appcmd, scripting, powershell, directly editing configuration etc).